# My array is full of null

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
package assign;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class tests {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("How many sous chef do we have?");
int two = s.nextInt();
if(two <= 0) { 
    do { 
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number:");
    two = s.nextInt();
    }while (two <= 0); 
    }
String [] souschef = new String[two];
for (int m = 0; m < souschef.length; m++) { 
    System.out.println("Enter the name of sous chef"+ m + ":");
    String f = s.next();
    f = souschef [m];
}
for (int i = 0; i < souschef.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(souschef[i]);
}
}
}
```

It doesnt matter how many names i enter, the output is all null. Didn't the for loop filled the array? For example i enter 3 names : John, Jack and Bob. Shouldn't the

```
for (int i = 0; i < souschef.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(souschef[i]);
    }
```

loop give me

> John Jack Bob

But the output is

> null null null

Thanks!!

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
f = souschef[m];
```

to

```
souschef[m] = f;
```

You want to fill the `souchef` array with what you have read from the input (`f`), not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you very much. When i first wrote it was like you said. Seems that i changed it for no reason.,

Answer (score 0):

Just change your loop to:

```
for (int m = 0; m < souschef.length; m++) { 
    System.out.println("Enter the name of sous chef"+ m + ":");
    String f = s.next();
    souschef [m]=f; //Assign f to String array
}
```

In your program you were taking input from user in variable `f` but assigning it to a null using `f=souschef [m];`

Comment: Thank you very much. When i first wrote it  was like you said.  Seems that i changed it for no reason.